# Sequential numbering for each month on a period of time in R

Tags: r

I have set of dates for a period of 10 years starting April 2006 till August 2016 i.e. 125 months. I want to identify each month by marking them out by sequential numbering starting from "1" till "125" in corresponding column (new column).
Example:
All dates in Apr'2006 will be identified as 1...May'2006 as 2 ...... Aug'2016 as 125.

Dates in the data set is in format type.

Requesting guidance on how to achieve this.

Comment: "format type"? Do you mean they are of class `Date`? Or something else?

Comment: if your data is ordered as you've mentioned, add a new column to your dataset using `seq(1,125)`

Comment: Date in factor type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that you start with a vector of dates in factor format:

```
x<- as.factor(c("8/7/2006", "12/13/2006", "12/14/2006"))
```

First you should convert this vector to Date format. In your case this can be done like this

```
x<- as.Date(x, format= "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Using the format command you can delete the day of a specific date:

```
format(x, "%Y %m")
> "2006 08" "2006 12" "2006 12"
```

This way you get rid of the day and just keep year and month.
Next you define a reference vector which contains all months from April 2006 to August 2016:

```
 ref<- seq(from= as.Date("04/01/2006", format= "%m/%d/%Y"), to= as.Date("08/01/2016", format= "%m/%d/%Y"), length.out = 125)
 ref<- format(ref, "%Y %m").
```

Finally you compare the entries from x with the entries from ref. This can be done with the sapply function which basically applies a function to each component of x. Here, the function it applies is the function:

```
 myfun<-function(z) {
    which(ref == format(z, "%Y %m"))
}
```

But since you do not need the function myfun elsewhere you can directly plug it into the sapply funtion. In the end you use the command unlist, so you get a vector.

```
  sapply(x, function(z) which(ref == format(z, "%Y %m")))
 > 6 10 10
```

should do the trick.

Comment: While using<br/>format(as.Date(Raw_Data$PROCESS_DATE, format = "%m/%d/%y"),"%Y %b")<br/> But I am getting 2020 Apr .... 2020 Dec. It seems it taking all year as "2020" but month is coming our perfectly. Henc e was not able to proceed further. Also please let me know what in (z) in function(z). <br/> Data is if factor format hence changed it to Date.

Comment: I am able to understand (z) but the incorrect year is the problem :(

Comment: is your date vector in date format? You can check using class(x).

Answer (score 1):

Using `lubridate` to format the dates:

```
library(lubridate)

# Create a data frame from the string below, as a factor variable
dat <- '8/7/2006 12/13/2006 12/14/2006 12/15/2006 12/16/2006 8/28/2007 8/29/2007 4/22/2008 4/23/2008 4/24/2008 4/25/2008 4/28/2008 4/29/2008 4/30/2008 5/1/2008 5/2/2008 5/7/2016 5/7/2016 5/7/2016 5/7/2016 6/26/2016 7/4/2016 7/31/2016 8/28/2016'
test_df <- data.frame(original=as.factor(strsplit(dat, ' ')[[1]]))

# We will need to convert the dates to strings in the right format
test_df$converted_string <- as.character(floor_date(mdy(test_df$original), unit="month"))

# Create a lookup table
my_months <- seq(125)
names(my_months) <- seq(as.Date('2006-04-01'), by='month', length.out=125)

# Do the lookup
test_df$converted_int <- my_months[test_df$converted_string]
```

Comment: sorry for not adding data set example. Below is the sample data set. 8/7/2006
12/13/2006
12/14/2006
12/15/2006
12/16/2006
8/28/2007
8/29/2007
4/22/2008
4/23/2008
4/24/2008
4/25/2008
4/28/2008
4/29/2008
4/30/2008
5/1/2008
5/2/2008
5/7/2016
5/7/2016
5/7/2016
5/7/2016
6/26/2016
7/4/2016
7/31/2016
8/28/2016, It's factor type

Comment: I am still understanding stackoverflow hence I apologize for data set not in proper format

Comment: See above; I've put the intermediate step as a separate column in the data.frame for clarity

Comment: Thanks for your patience and guidance. It has worked